# Unable to uninstall mysql-connector-python in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: mysql, 19.04

My Java Sir told me to install MySQL-server, workbench, and connector. I did that somehow after spending 30+ hours reading different posts.

After launching Workbench, I went to Tools > Start Shell for MySQL Utilities. Which gave me this popup: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fHso.jpg

Pressing Download option redirected me to [this](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/utilities/) website:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeAPy.jpg

After installing this package, whenever I run: **sudo apt update**, I get this error:

```
pranav@inspiron-5548:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for pranav: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mysql-connector-python
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 1,362 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 216555 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mysql-connector-python (8.0.16-1ubuntu19.04) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.sysconfig'
dpkg: error processing package mysql-connector-python (--remove):
 installed mysql-connector-python package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-connector-python
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So, I thought I should uninstall this, and I used
 **sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-connector-python** command, but it also didn't work, and it throws me the same error as above.

What to do? I am in limbo here! Since any new development done in "mysql-utilities" is aged back to Jan 17, 2017, I don't think I will be needing this anymore. I did the mistake trying to install old archived deb package. (newbie)

*IF u know, how to remove it, what is it, it would be really helpful to tell me about it.*

Comment: Possible off-topic question. Your title says Ubuntu 19.10 (the development release), but you have tagged 19.04.  Ubuntu 19.10 (which I am using myself) is off-topic here due to development status, it has support via irc & other methods - but not here.

Comment: @guiverc sorry. I did a stupid silly typing mistake. Why would I ever use development release? I didn't see that coming... sorry.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt -f install`  (ie. --fix-broken) or `dpkg --purge` instead of using the `apt-get` frontend?

Comment: @guiverc I get same above error, with dpkg. What else can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally,  `sudo apt autoremove` should have worked but in this case, I used this command to the solved same issue:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-connector-python* /tmp
```

After using the above command, use `sudo apt autoremove` again and that will solve everything.

For more details about this issue, visit [this](https://itsfoss.com/dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1/) site.